# Get email from bitbucket

Tags: php, symfony, http, oauth, bitbucket

I need to implement bitbucket authorization on Symfony2 project. I`m using HWIOAuthBundle and Guzzle for forming request. To get emails I need to get json response from 
https://bitbucket.org/api/1.0/users/{accountname}/emails
But every time i get

> Client error response [url] https://bitbucket.org/api/1.0/users/{accountname}/emails [status code] 401 [reason phrase] UNAUTHORIZED"

But i`m already authorized at Bitbucket .
Here is my code:

```
$url = 'https://bitbucket.org/api/1.0/users/'.$response->getUsername().'/emails';
    $client = new Client();
    $request = $client->createRequest('GET', $url);
    $emails = $client->send($request);
```

Comment: do you use it in Symfony? This type of call require client's authentication

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are not providing an access token when making requests, therefore Bitbucket is rejecting them with a 401.

From their [docs](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/OAuth+on+Bitbucket#OAuthonBitbucket-Accesstokens):

> Once you have an access token, as per RFC-6750, you can use it in a request in any of the following ways (listed from most to least desirable):
>
> 1. Send it in a request header: Authorization: Bearer {access_token}
> 2. Include it in a (application/x-www-form-urlencoded) POST body as access_token={access_token}
> 3. Put in the query string of a non-POST: ?access_token={access_token}

I would first lookup the docs of the OAuth library you are using and find out how to get a user's access token for a specific service (Bitbucket in your case). Then, I would include it in the request headers in Guzzle:

```
$client = new Client();

$request = $client->createRequest(
    'GET',
    'https://bitbucket.org/api/1.0/users/' . $response->getUsername() . '/emails',
    [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $userOauthAccessToken,
    ]
);

$emails = $client->send($request);
```